# Identifying a wooden puzzle box

Tags: puzzle-identification, mechanical-puzzles

In a flashback sequence in the film Tomb Raider (2018), Lara is seen trying to solve a wooden puzzle box:

[image]

It is reminiscent of the [Karakuri group](https://karakuri.gr.jp/en/products/kk-1/)'s "small box" puzzles, but I was not able to find one in [their catalogue](https://karakuri.gr.jp/en/products) of the same design.

Can anyone identify this puzzle?

Comment: It might be [this one](https://yosegijapan.com/yosegi-products/hbiom208/)? The one in the film seems smaller though.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis ah - the yosegi/pattern is the same, but this one is [a cube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azQay.png) (not rectangle). Maybe an older model by the same company?

Comment: That's not necessarily a cube, but it does have a square side. [Here](https://www.seriouspuzzles.com/2-sun-10-step-kuroasa-japanese-puzzle-box-discon/) is a smaller, simpler puzzle box with the same pattern, but still not with a square side. The one in the film seems to have a much finer pattern, definitely higher quality, matching my previous link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @JaapScherphuis for pointing me to a similar puzzle by Izumiya's Hakone Parquet Marquetry Shop. This appears to be by the same company/designer, shown [here](https://www.pinterest.co.uk/pin/145522631683961936/):

| [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- |

But appears to have been [discontinued](https://puzzleboxworld.com/products/3-step-karakuri-japanese-puzzle-box-small-cube-1-kuroasa).

Some online shops list it as [Karakuri Small Box #1: KA (Kuroasa)](https://www.seriouspuzzles.com/karakuri-small-box-1-ka-kuroasa-japanese-puzzle-box-discon/) (though this pattern is not among the 3 ["Small Box #1" variants](https://www.karakuri.gr.jp/creation/small-box/small-box.htm) listed on Karakuri's site).

The yosegi pattern is known as [kuroasa](https://kubiyagames.com/blogs/mechanical-puzzles-blog/the-history-of-the-japanese-puzzle-box#:%7E:text=Kuroasa%20means%20%E2%80%9Cdark%20morning%2C%E2%80%9D,made%20with%20a%20dark%20wood.):

> Kuroasa means “dark morning,” or “dark sunrise,” and consists of interlocking star shaped patterns made with a dark wood.